# slow mysql query that has to execute hundreds of thousand of times per hour

Tags: mysql, database-performance

My mysql database has a table with several hundred thousand rows.
Each row has (amongst other data) a user name and a time stamp.

I need to retrieve the record with the most recent timestamp for a given user.

The current, brute force query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE `user_name`="The user name" AND datetime_sent = (SELECT MAX(`datetime_sent`) FROM tableName WHERE `user_name`="The user name");
```

The table has an index on `user_name` and on `datetime_sent`.

How can I best improve this query?  I have to run thousands of these queries at a time.  Each query seems to be taking between 1 and 4 milliseconds and I suspect there is a much more efficient way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from tableName
where userName = 'username'
order by datetime_sent desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Juergen - I tried it and, to my surprise, execution of approximately the same number of queries took longer (about 15% longer) than the original.

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. But I can't come up with a solution that is faster. Have you tried to change your `datetime_sent`index from `asc` to `desc`?