# MYSQL , INNODB Alternative Search Query In Big Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Now i have a table with more than 250,000 records, and now i want to make custom search engine for this.

When i used standard query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%word%' OR column2 LIKE '%word%' LIMIT 20` , it work but give slow performance  , are there other query to give same result with fast performance ?

**I use INNODB with mysql 5.0 , so i can't add FULLTEXT index .**

[image: This is My Table Structure]

Comment: First of all why are you repeating the same condition on the same column in the query with an OR?

Comment: ops im type it must SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%word%' OR column2 LIKE '%word%'

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/how-to-speed-up-queries-on-a-large-220-million-rows-table-9-gig-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754675/slow-mysql-query-that-has-to-execute-hundreds-of-thousand-of-times-per-hour and http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/195905/Tips-and-Tricks-to-Optimize-MySQL and http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/ - Plus, have you any indexes? That could be an issue, as well as if you have any unneeded loops, or including DB connection inside a loop.

Comment: Also, selecting actual columns instead of all `*` could also be a contributing factor. 250,000 records shouldn't be too much for MySQL. Some even query millions with fairly good performance. Define "slow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other full text search technologies.

You know that you can't use FULLTEXT indexes in an InnoDB table in MySQL 5.0, but you could  copy the searchable text data to a MyISAM table, and use FULLTEXT indexes there. I wouldn't recommend making the MyISAM table be the *only* copy of that data. Treat it as a volatile copy, like a cache, because MyISAM is so susceptible to corruption.

There are also third-party text search technologies like Sphinx Search, Apache Solr, Xapian, etc. These also would involve copying the text data to the full text index.

And a pure InnoDB approach would be to create an N-gram index to your text data.

I compare some of these methods in my presentation [Fulltext Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).